# Why is my loop through a form control array stopping one short?

Tags: vb.net

I have done a for each loop on form controls before.  I don't think it's complicated code.  I've used the same method I'm using now, but for some reason the loop is stopping one short.

One thing to note is that my controls are made thusly:

```
For i As Integer = 1 To sheetCount
   Dim wb As New WebBrowser
   With wb
      .Name = "pqCheck" & i
      .Navigate(New Uri(savePath & "PQ Check Sheet " & i & ".pdf"))
      .Location = New Point(((i - 1) * (screenWidth / sheetCount)), browserHeight)
      .Size = New Size(screenWidth / sheetCount, screenHeight - browserHeight)
      .ScrollBarsEnabled = False
      form.Controls.Add(wb)
   End With
Next
```

I do this for reasons.  But I'm curious to know if creating controls this way somehow confuses my loop to think all the controls made this way share some sort of identifier.  (Should note that I make a lot of controls this way in my projects, and have been able to successfully loop through each control before without issue.)

```
Dim cnt As Integer = 0
Debug.Print("Controls: " & frmMain.Controls.Count)
For Each cControl In frmMain.Controls
   If TypeOf cControl Is WebBrowser Then
      If cControl.Name.Contains("pqCheck") Then
         cControl.Dispose()
      End If
      cnt += cnt
      Debug.Print("Loop Count: " & cnt)
   End If
Next
```

Debug outputs:

```
Controls: 3
Loop Count: 1
Loop Count: 2
```

No loop count 3.  I am confused.

Comment: Could you have a `control` that is not of type `WebBrowser`? Move your `Debug.Print("Loop Count: " & cnt)` outside of the `If TypeOf` to see if that's the issue.

Comment: cnt += cnt should be  cnt += 1 but that does not explain why it's only going through 2 times

Comment: are you sure all controls are of type WebBrower?

Comment: @user2818985 - I missed that, but it wouldn't be the reason for only two `Debug.Print`s, only that the third (if it happened) would be `Loop Count: 4` instead of 3.

Comment: Moving loop count outside of the TypeOf test resulted in the same.  And thanks for that cnt=>1.  My brain missed that today.  And yes, all controls are of type WebBrowser.

Comment: Clarification: One WebBrowser is created at design time.  The other two are created at run time.  The WB created in design is cleverly called WebBrowser1.  The two I create at run time are called pqCheck1 and pqCheck2.

Comment: Try putting in an Else to see what the other control is

Comment: @Benno - the Else doesn't ever get hit.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should copy the Controls collection into an array before disposing of the WebBrower controls

```
 Dim arr(frmMain.Controls.Count) As Control
    Controls.CopyTo(arr, 0)

    Dim cnt As Integer = 0
    Debug.Print("Controls: " & frmMain.Controls.Count)
    For Each cControl In arr
        If TypeOf cControl Is WebBrowser Then
            If cControl.Name.Contains("pqCheck") Then
                cControl.Dispose()
            End If
            cnt += cnt
            Debug.Print("Loop Count: " & cnt)
        End If
    Next
```

You need to create a separate list of the references because Dispose also will remove the control from the collection, changing the index and messing up the foreach statement

Comment: That makes sense (not sure why the answer is at -1). Trying it now, but can't use the array to check name of control this way.

Comment: @gCanuck - _can't use the array to check name of control this way_  Why not?  The controls will still have it's name property.

Comment: @ChrisDunaway - Mostly because I'm too ignorant to figure out how to do that. *shrug*

Answer (score 0):

Special shout-out to user2818985 for pointing me in the right direction.  It all came down to the index of the controls.  When you dispose of a control, it will adjust the index and screw things up a bit (a lot).

To solve this, simply reverse the loop.  (I'm sure I can fine tune this, but it works, so ya us! Go team and all that.)

```
For i As Integer = frmMain.Controls.Count To 0 Step -1
    For Each cControl In frmMain.Controls
        If TypeOf cControl Is WebBrowser Then
            If cControl.Name.Contains("pqCheck") Then
                cControl.Dispose()
            End If
            cnt += 1
        Else
            Debug.Print("Else Control: " & cControl.Name)
        End If
        Debug.Print("Loop Count: " & cnt)
    Next
Next
```